# Do we have $\log (1-x)=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^k}k$ for every $x\in\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, power-series

$\log (1-x)=-\sum^{\infty}_{k=1}\frac{x^k}k$ for every $x\in\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$?

LHS and RHS are both holomorphic except for $x=1$ so we can use the analytic continuation theorem. But it looks so unbelievable and I think there should be an error. Is it really true?

Comment: neither LHS nor RHS are actually holomorphic for $x\in\mathbb{C}-\{1\}$ as LHS need a branch cut from $1$ to infinity to be well defined, while RHS doesn't converge for $|x|>1$; the result definitely holds for $|x|<1$ with the principal branch of the logarithm taken for LHS; summation by parts shows that RHS converges for $|x|=1, x \ne 1$ and some standard theorems show that the eqaulity can be extended there indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not true. For instance, the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}k$ converges if and only of $|x|<1$. So, the RHS doesn't even make sense when $|x|\geqslant1$. However, the equality holds when $|x|<1$, assuming that here $\log$ is the main branch of the logarithm.

Comment: the equality actually can be extended to $|x| \le 1, x \ne 1$ as RHS converges (sum by parts) and is continuous there by standard abelian theorems (summation by parts is uniform on any compact circle set avoiding $1$); incidentally the statement in the answer about $|x| \ge 1$ is not true as the series definitely converges for $|x|=1, x \ne 1$ (see $x=-1$ which gives the well known $\log 2$ formula